# Como recoger parametros de un Json desde el servidor con .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

En una función JavaScript uso ***`__doPostBack`*** para enviar 2 parámetros con sus valores al servidor. Los valores los envío en formato JSON pero no se como recogerlos utilizando .NET 3.5

En el cliente JavaScript:

```
 __doPostBack("Actualizar", JSON.stringify({ valor: variable1, indice: variable2 }));
```

En el servidor C#:

```
string valueName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");
```

Donde valueName puede ser igual a: `"{\"valor\":\"5\",\"indice\":2}"`

¿Que función o código puedo usar para deserializar un JSON con .NET 3.5 (Visual Studio 2008)?

```
string valor = mifuncionDeserializaJson(valueName).valor;
string indice = mifuncionDeserializaJson(valueName).indice;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), solo debes agregar la referencia.

**Opción 1**: utilizando la clase ***JObject***.

```
string valueName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");

JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(valueName);

string valor = (string)jsonObj.GetValue("valor");
int indice = (int)jsonObj.GetValue("indice");
```

También existe el metodo `TryGetValue` [ver documentacion](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_TryGetValue.htm).

---

**Opción 2**: está en particular debes de tener o crearte una clase adicional para la deserialización:

Te creas una clase, con un nombre significativo para el request que estas realizando, en el ejemplo la nombre `RequestViewModel`, pero puedes cambiarle el nombre.

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public int indice { get; set; }
}
```

Y la deserialización:

```
string valueName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");

RequestViewModel rqst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestViewModel>(valueName);

string valor = rqst.valor;
int indice = rqst.indice;
```

> **Más información sobre**: [DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) y [Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm).

Si tienes problemas a la hora de agregar la librería entonces puedes descargar de forma directa la dll ([descargar el releases](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases)). cuando descomprimas él .zip encontraras una carpeta llamada bin y dentro de ellas las diferentes versiones, en tú caso sería la dll que está dentro de la carpeta net35.

---

**Opción 3**: para esta opción no se utiliza el *Newtonsoft.Json*, si no, que debes agregar una referencia a **`System.Web.Extensions`** y utilizar el espacio de nombre **`System.Web.Script.Serialization`**. Para esta opción también debes crearte una clase.

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public int indice { get; set; }
}
```

Y la deserialización:

```
string valueName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RequestViewModel rqst = ser.Deserialize<RequestViewModel>(valueName);

string valor = rqst.valor;
int indice = rqst.indice;
```

> **Más información sobre**: [JavaScriptSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-3.5)

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json no lo puedo instalar en mi visual 2008

Comment: No nesecitas instalar nada, solo debes agregar la dll como referencia. Al final de la respuesta te dejo la opcion de descargar la libreria de forma manual.

Comment: @Popularfan e agregado un tercera opcion donde solo debes agregar una referencia a una libreria, con esta opcion no debes de instalar o descargar una libreria externa.

Comment: Me sirvió la opción 3